# Always getting { "code": 401, "message": "Bad credentials" }

Tags: symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

i started using the LexikJWTBundle but when i try to create the token it always returns me bad credentials i didn't know where is the problem if it's the password or bad configuration i like done everything but still not working is there any idea of from where the problem is coming from

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
       App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous : true
        json_login :
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    main:
        anonymous: true

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to regenerate the SSH keys like in following link to documentation:
[LexikJWT Documentation](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation)
And make sure you configured right the `pass_phrase`

Comment: problem solved it was just a bad password hash but thanks anyway